# CUDA CUFFT on Shield Tablet

Tags: android, cuda, cufft

I have tried to modify the CUDA samples on Shield Tablet by using CUFFT. However, when I build the program, I got the link errors: `undefined reference to 'cufftExecR2C'`; `undefined reference to 'cufftExecC2R'`.

I thought the errors may cause by missing .so file. Then I added the libcufft.so in the 
Android.mk file, like:

```
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_MODULE := libcufft
 LOCAL_LIB_PATH += $(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT)/targets/armv7-linux-    androideabi/lib/
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_LIB_PATH)/libcufft.so
 include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I still got the same errors. Could anyone please help me and point me to right direction?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`  looks wrong. Just by its name, you wouldn't add a shared library there, I would guess.

Comment: Thanks for your @talonmies suggestion, I have tried this way. Unfortunately, it is still not working.

Comment: try `LOCAL_MODULE := cufft` and add `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := cufft`

Comment: There two different questions, the first one was mentioned above and been resolved by your advise, then the another error come out, so I put the second question. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your suggestion.